# Storage shows more space used than actually used

Tags: storage, disk-space

I got my Mac 2 days ago and installed a few softwares, Xcode, Android Studio and stuff. Today I noticed my Storage as this:

[image]

17GB of Apps might be there but I dont have any Audio/Photos! Where is this 2GB going? And whats this 13Gb other?

Is there an app that can locate these files taking this space?

Comment: we have the same question like million times. The other is all the files that do not fit the preset (shown) categories. For the audio 1.19 GB, you need to check that, but know that new Macs come with preloaded "how to" instructions from Apple, and once you do not need them you can delete that.

Comment: @Buscar웃 And how can I delete those files? Where are they locates?